# How do I get fastavro to support logical types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro, fastavro

I am trying to use a logical type in Avro, with the Python **fastavro** library to read and write, but the `logicalType` annotation seems to have no effect at all. The code below is taken from the [**fastavro** page](https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/); I have altered the **time** field in the schema definition by annotating it with the logical type **time-millis**, in accordance with [the current Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Time+%28millisecond+precision%29).  (On a side note, I have seen people use **TIMESTAMP_MILLIS**, but I do not know why, since the Avro page has **time-millis**.)  When I run this code, the output I see in stdout is exactly the same as the output of the same code without the logical type annotation.  I was expecting to see something that looked like a time--e.g., **13:14:15.1234**.  Yet the **fastavro** page cited above claims that **fastavro** now supports Avro logical types.  How can I get it to do so?  Thanks!

```
from fastavro import writer, reader, parse_schema

schema = {
    'doc': 'A weather reading.',
    'name': 'Weather',
    'namespace': 'test',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'station', 'type': 'string'},
        {'name': 'time', 'type': 'int', 'logicalType': 'time-millis'},
        {'name': 'temp', 'type': 'int'},
    ],
}
parsed_schema = parse_schema(schema)

# 'records' can be an iterable (including generator)
records = [
    {u'station': u'011990-99999', u'temp': 0, u'time': 1433269388},
    {u'station': u'011990-99999', u'temp': 22, u'time': 1433270389},
    {u'station': u'011990-99999', u'temp': -11, u'time': 1433273379},
    {u'station': u'012650-99999', u'temp': 111, u'time': 1433275478},
]

# Writing
with open('weather.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, parsed_schema, records)

# Reading
with open('weather.avro', 'rb') as fo:
    for record in reader(fo):
        print(record)
```

The output to stdout, whether the `logicalType` annotation is present or removed, is the same:

'station': '011990-99999', 'time': 1433269388, 'temp': 0}

```
{'station': '011990-99999', 'time': 1433270389, 'temp': 22}
{'station': '011990-99999', 'time': 1433273379, 'temp': -11}
{'station': '012650-99999', 'time': 1433275478, 'temp': 111}
```

I can see that the schemas in the output files are different between the two versions:

With `logicalType` specified:

```
"fields": [{"name": "station", "type": "string"}, {"logicalType": "time-millis", "name": "time", "type": "int"}, {"name": "temp", "type": "int"}]
```

Without `logicalType` specified:

```
"fields": [{"name": "station", "type": "string"}, {"name": "time", "type": "int"}, {"name": "temp", "type": "int"}]
```

But this makes no difference in the output.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer is that the type specification must be treated as, itself, a schema, so the syntax is different.  In the above example, the schema should be defined as follows:

schema = {
    'doc': 'A weather reading.',
    'name': 'Weather',
    'namespace': 'test',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'station', 'type': 'string'},
        {'name': 'time', 'type': {'type': 'int', 'logicalType': 'time-millis'}},
        {'name': 'temp', 'type': 'int'},
    ],